# Extend/Override .phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, extend

I have a third party module, and I'm trying to override the third party .phtml file but it's not working for me. For these, I tried below ways.

Third-Party Layout module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="quotation_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
          <referenceBlock name="quotation.quote.item.renderers">
               <block class="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Magebees_QuotationManager::quote/item/default.phtml">
                    <block class="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="quotation.quote.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                        <block class="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="quotation.quote.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magebees_QuotationManager::quote/item/edit.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="quotation.quote.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magebees_QuotationManager::quote/item/remove.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>         
        </referenceBlock> 
    </body>
</page>
```

Now I want to Override `quote/item/default.phtml` file.

I tried 2 Ways.

1) Extended luma theme

Copied `default.phtml` file and pasted in `design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magebees_QuotationManager/templates/quote/item/default.phtml`

After the above step I executed the `upgrade, compile, static-content: deploy` commands, still not working.

2) Tried with `di.xml`

created `di.xml` in `etc/frontend/di.xml` and written below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer"  type="ABCSolutions\CQWCProduct\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer" />
</config>
```

And I set the template in the Block file see below code.

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\CQWCProduct\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item;

use Magebees\QuotationManager\Helper\Quotation;
use Magebees\QuotationManager\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\InterpretationStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Renderer extends \Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer{


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Configuration $qproductConfig,
        Quotation $quoteHelper,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        ImageBuilder $imageBuilder,
        Data $urlHelper,
        ManagerInterface $qmessageManager,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        InterpretationStrategyInterface $qmessageInterpretationStrategy,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $qproductConfig, $quoteHelper, $checkoutSession, $imageBuilder, $urlHelper, $qmessageManager, $priceCurrency, $moduleManager,
            $qmessageInterpretationStrategy, $quoteFactory, $data);
        $this->setTemplate("ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct::quote/item/default.phtml");
    }

}
```

In `default.phtml` file pasted the code from the Magebees module & added extra content with "Extended".

Still not getting the updated design.

Please suggest me if I went wrong?

Comment: Did you give sequence in your module.xml file?

Comment: @RohanHapani Yes, given.

Comment: @RohanHapani, I have given ` <module name="ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct" setup_version="0.1.1" />
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magebees_QuotationManager"/>
        </sequence>`

Comment: Did you upgrade your module after add sequence?

Comment: @RohanHapani, Yes, Executed the `upgrade, compile & static-content:deploy` commands. still not working

Comment: you can extend a theme with the same name. you should give it a custom name

Comment: Your module.xml code is not proper. Which you added in comment.

Comment: @RohanHapani, `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct" setup_version="0.1.1" />
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magebees_QuotationManager"/>
        </sequence>
</config>`

Comment: The first method which you tried is absolutely fine but make sure the file path and the theme is configured for the current store.

Comment: secondly make the theme name must to somethign rather than luma for ur extended theme, hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved my self by using the 2nd Method in my thread.

**di.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer"   type="ABCSolutions\CQWCProduct\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer"/>

</config>
```

**Renderer.php** file

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\CQWCProduct\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item;

use Magebees\QuotationManager\Helper\Quotation;
use Magebees\QuotationManager\Model\QuoteFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Message\InterpretationStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magebees\QuotationManager\Model\QuoteFilesFactory;

class Renderer extends \Magebees\QuotationManager\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer{


    /**
     * @var QuoteFilesFactory
     */
    protected $_quoteFilesFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Configuration $qproductConfig,
        Quotation $quoteHelper,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        ImageBuilder $imageBuilder,
        Data $urlHelper,
        ManagerInterface $qmessageManager,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        InterpretationStrategyInterface $qmessageInterpretationStrategy,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        QuoteFilesFactory $quoteFilesFactory,
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $qproductConfig, $quoteHelper, $checkoutSession, $imageBuilder, $urlHelper, $qmessageManager, $priceCurrency, $moduleManager,
            $qmessageInterpretationStrategy, $quoteFactory, $data);
        $this->_quoteFilesFactory = $quoteFilesFactory;
        $this->setTemplate("ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct::quote/item/default.phtml");
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->setTemplate("ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct::quote/item/default.phtml");
        return $this;
    } 

}
```

**default.phtml** file

added "Extended" content.

Comment: just wondering was this layout handle added dynamically from Magebees module with: `$resultPage->addHandle('new_layout_handle');` type code?
 
I'm having similar issues it seems like these handles when added that way do not check for the corresponding layout in other modules besides itself, maybe is a Magento 2 bug?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your syntax issue in your `module.xml` :

**Your code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct" setup_version="0.1.1" />
   <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
      <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
      <module name="Magebees_QuotationManager"/>
   </sequence>
</config>
```

**Replace with this below code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct" setup_version="0.1.1">
       <sequence>
          <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
          <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
          <module name="Magebees_QuotationManager"/>
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then, do upgrade process.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Let's try and coma back.

Comment: Still, not working bro.

Comment: Oh..!! Strange..!! It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="quotation_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="default">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::quote/item/default.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**OR**

```
<referenceBlock name="default" template="Vendor_Module::quote/item/default.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let's try and come back

Comment: I have tried the above 2 methods in my module `quotation.quote.item.renderers.xml` layout file, but not working for me. I'm I fallowed correct or wrong? please suggest.

Comment: what is your xml file name? `quotation.quote.item.renderers.xml` or `quotation_quote_item_renderers.xml`

Comment: The layout file name is `quotation_quote_item_renderers.xml`.

Comment: Understood, wait a minute will try again.

Comment: Renamed file from `quotation.quote.item.renderers.xml` or `quotation_quote_item_renderers.xml`, still not working.

Comment: I fallowed 2nd Method in my thread and added extra function `protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->setTemplate("ABCSolutions_CQWCProduct::quote/item/default.phtml");
        return $this;
    }` now working fine. Thank you for your help.